# PHP if not found in foreach run function again

Tags: php, function, syntax, foreach

I have a block of code below. But first let me explain on what I am trying to do:

I have an API call that gets stories based off offset and limit, what I am trying to do is if the story I am looking is not in the first 100 stories, run the API again to the next 100 stories. The way I am trying to do this is by calling my function inside my function. Can I call my function inside its own function? Or is there a better way to do this?

Here is my first function call:

```
$storyCounter = 0;
$pageCounter = 1;
$pageNumber = 1;
$foundStory = false;
$story_id = 426;
$offset = 0;
$limit = 100;
$this->getStoryPage($offset, $limit);
```

and here is my function, this is placed before the code above:

```
function getStoryPage($offset, $amount){
    $Api = new Api();
    $storyPage = $Api->getStory($offset, $amount);

    foreach($storyPage->stories as $row => $value){

        if($value->storyId == $story_id){
            $foundStroy = true;
            break;
        }
        $storyCounter++;
        if($storyCounter == 12){
            $pageCounter++;
            $storyCounter = 0;
        }
    }
    if($storyEpisode){
        $pageNumber = $pageCounter;
    }else{
        $offset += 100;
        $limit += 100;
        $this->getStoryPage($offset, $limit);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you find the story and then determine where it lies in the overall order of stories rather than trying to hunt and peck around for a story or at least make a best guess at the story page based on the autoincrement ID?

Comment: There are over 1400 stories, when trying to find the story the API timeouts. How do I recommend I find the story first?

Comment: From where do you fetch the stories? Hope you're using some database engine...

Comment: Are stories ordered by id value? If so, since you already know the story id, you should at least be able to make a best guess at the maximum page on which it could be found.  For example, in case with story id = 426 and paging limit of 100, you know that the highest number page id 426 can exist on is page 5.  It could exist on a lower number page if there are gaps in the id sequence, so if not on page 5, you could search for page 4.

Comment: Still this seems like an odd way to get at this data as in the DB you should be able to `SELECT COUNT(story_id) FROM table WHERE story_id <= $story_id ORDER BY story_id ASC` to determine exact position of story. You just take count value from this query and simply determine page like `$page = ceil($row_count/$page_limit);`